# Showing only ONE week (Opening hours, each week the same)

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to know if it is possible to show only one week, to use this calendar for showing opening hours of a shop.
So :
    - I don't want to show the day dates (only the day names) : OK
    - I don't want to colorize the current day : OK
    - I want the calendar display always the same week => I don't know how to do that...

Have you got any idea ? Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "goToDate" method:

> gotoDate
>
> Moves the calendar to an arbitrary
>   year/month/date.
>
> .fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year [,
>   month, [ date ]] )
>
> IMPORTANT: month is 0-based, meaning
>   January=0, February=1, etc.

you could add your shop opening hours on the calendar for a given date, and then just show the date. However, you could also just add them for the current week being shown - this would then allow you to change times, for example, bank holidays etc. Have an array of special dates and print normally if not one of those dates...

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.3 and 1.4 fullcalendar is now able to show week view:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/

Example:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/views/agendaWeek/