# Opening hours / fullcalendar for an "anonymous" week

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'd like to use full calendar to let users create opening hours for weekdays (Monday to Sunday, and if possible holidays). What fullcalendar already does, but it's not for a particular week in time so it should not have dates. So, questions:

- any ideas to not attach to a particular week? My best idea so far is to pick a particular week in time and hide dates.
- any idea to show an 8th day for holidays?

Comment: just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733061/showing-only-one-week-opening-hours-each-week-the-same?rq=1 which is related but old and doesn't solve the problem for holidays. Maybe there's a better way to do it now?

Comment: Also, solutions that don't use fullcalendar but have good usability (click, drag, etc) are acceptable.

Comment: Interesting discussion on UX of opening hours http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/33600/form-for-inputting-operating-hours-of-a-business

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used the agendaweek view for the the week, and save the data without the date 
start hour
end hour
weekday

then for every week i claculate the date and add to it the hour.

maybe fullcalendar is'nt the best thing for that.

Comment: fullcalendar is probably not the best thing for this, but I followed this suggestion, which is also one of the options in the question. I could not find a way to add another day for holidays easily.